# Using webhook for fulfillment Vs using Firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, webhooks, dialogflow-es

It might be a silly question, but what the difference between:

**Using webhook for fulfillment Vs using Firebase cloud functions?**

I know webhook goes to my own or my cloud server and firebase cloud function runs on firebase. Correct me if I am wrong.

Are there any other major differences? Or when should I use one over other?

[image]

PS - So far I was using Firebase cloud functions, but watched [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ7Pd.png) video and came to know I can use webhooks and send request to my server as well.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJ7Pd.png) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVNyUehBU2I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're intuition is right Puneet. Firebase cloud functions are just one kind of webhook fulfillment. You can totally use your own server for fulfillment if you want, we suggest Firebase functions because they're a convenient way to spin up an API endpoint if you don't already have a server.